# how can i change (sign out) my github account

Tags: github, signing

I signed in to GitHub with my email which has got banned couple of months ago, then after i signed in, i tried to sign out and sign in again with my another Gmail account but it kept showing me this error

[image: 1]

I tried to solve it by myself by getting into settings and figure out what really is wrong, but the setting icon didn't even appear when i clicked on my account. I also tried to watch YouTube videos to see if i could find any video that could help me solve this problem but there didn't seem to be one.

Comment: You got banned from GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things you can try doing:

1. Try refreshing your page using CTRL + Shift + R (if using Google Chrome)
2. Try logging in with another device.
3. Try logging in with another IP address (A VPN may be used)
4. Try logging in with a third account.
   If the issue persist, you should contact GitHub support [here](https://support.github.com/)